# Explicit formula for the nth term of the sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the sequence $\{0, 3, 8, 15, 24, 35,\dots\}$ and I need to find the explicit formula.

I am not sure how to go about doing this, but what I have started with is trying to find a way to express the changing variable getting added to the sequence.  Each term adds $2$ plus the previous term. $n_1 + 3$, $n_2 + 5$,$n_3 + 7$ and so on. I am not entirely sure how to express this in a formula.

Answer (score 3):

If we add 1 to all the numbers in the sequence, we immediately see the squares, so the explicit form is $a(n)=n^2-1$ (with the first term having index 0).

Answer (score 2):

For the sequence, $$a_0=0, a_1=3, a_2=8,  ...$$Your formula is $$a_n = n^2 + 2n,\text {  n $\ge 0 $ }$$

You can prove it by induction.

If you  want your sequence starts with $$a_1=0, a_2 =3, a_3 =8,...$$
Then the formula will be $$a_n = n^2 -1 , n\ge 1$$